# How to set multiple inputs depending on previous user input

Tags: python, input

So I am new to the world of coding and got this assignment and cant figure out how to get this done.

Lets say for example that I ask the user to choose between 1 to 5 sheep's.

Once I receive his input, I would like to ask him to provide names for each one of the ships and set the amount of possible inputs to the amount of sheep's he would like to name.

For example:

```
def sheep_namer():
x = input('Please enter a number of sheep's (1-5): ')
x = int(x)
if 1 <= x <= 5:
    y = input ('Please enter sheep names\n ')
    #if x = 1, so user is only allowed 1 input before code continues. Same idea for x = 2 etc...

    
else:
    print('The number you entered is not between 1 and 5, goodbye!')`
```

So what I am trying to achieve here is that I only allow an amount of inputs that fits the amount of sheep's he would like to name.
Any ideas?
thanks

Comment: Your code does not match your question.  You need a loop of some kind.  Say the use entered three.  You'd need to ask for three sheep names.  Your code does not even attempt that.

Answer (score 0):

Using a for loop:

```
def sheep_namer():
  x = int(input('Please enter a number of sheep's (1-5): '))
  for y in range(0,x):
    k = input("Please enter sheep name "+y+":")
```

You can get each input at each iteration with k variable.

Answer (score 0):

You need a loop to get the sheep names and a list to store them.

Try this code:

```
def sheep_namer():
    x = input('Please enter a number of sheep\'s (1-5): ')
    x = int(x)
    if 1 <= x <= 5:
        names = []
        print(f'Please enter {x} sheep names (1 per line) ')
        for ctr in range(x):
            y = input()
            names.append(y)
        return names
    else:
        print('The number you entered is not between 1 and 5, goodbye!')
        
print('Sheep Names:', sheep_namer())
```

Output

```
Please enter a number of sheep's (1-5): 3
Please enter 3 sheep names (1 per line)
larry
curly
moe
Sheep Names: ['larry', 'curly', 'moe']
```

Comment: How do I prevent the loop from re printing "please enter sheep name" and just have the user type in his input one beneath the other?

Answer (score 0):

Try using a for loop:

```
def sheep_namer():
    x = input('Please enter the number of sheep (1-5): ')
    x = int(x)
    if not (1 <= x <= 5):
        print('The number you entered is not between 1 and 5, goodbye!')
    else:
        sheep_names = []
        print("Please enter sheep names:")
        for i in range(x):
            y = input()
            sheep_names.append(y)
```

Or, here is the shortened (but a bit less intuitive) code:

```
def sheep_namer():
    x = int(input('Please enter a number of sheep (1-5): '))
    if not (1 <= x <= 5):
        print('The number you entered is not between 1 and 5, goodbye!')
    else:
        print("Please enter sheep names:")
        sheep_names = [input() for i in range(x)]
```

These both loop over the number of sheep, asking the name with an empty input() (so as to not print out a question everytime), and store that in a list.
The end result of these would be the sheep_names variable containing the names of the sheep, like this:
sheep_names = ['First sheep', 'Second sheep', 'Third sheep']